# Can I minify JSON-LD without affecting the output in search engines?

Tags: rich-snippets, json-ld

Can these type of scripts be minified without affecting the output in search engines?

Example script:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "example.com",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "example.com",
      "logo": "example.com/logo.png"
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only minify it on the HTML way, with deleting of needless spaces, like:

```
{"@context":"some-domain.com","@type":"Organization","url":"some-domain.com","logo":"some-domain.com/logo.png"}
```

Its functionality remains.